# Object search for key value and remove the first and last characters in it

Tags: javascript

I have an object which looks like this:

```
obj = {file: "file.doc", myData: "['dat1','dat2']"}
```

What I need to do is to have some code that will search inside the object for myData and replace the surrounding quotes between the [].

For example:

Search for: `"['dat1','dat2']"` in `myData: "['dat1','dat2']"}` and remove the quotes so the end result would look like this:

```
{file: "file.doc", myData: ['dat1','dat2']}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: var myval = obj.match(/"(.*)/); but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take the string, remove the brackets, use a regex to replace all singlequotes and then split it based on the comma that is left between all items.

```js
obj = {file: "file.doc", myData: "['dat1','dat2']"}
var str = obj.myData.replace(/'/g,"").replace("[","").replace("]","");
obj.myData = str.split(",");
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can replace the single quotes `'` with double quotes and then use `JSON.parse`

```js
let obj = {
  file: "file.doc",
  myData: "['dat1','dat2']"
}
let k = obj.myData.replace(/'/g, '"');
let output = JSON.parse(k);
obj.myData = output;

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Why specifically use JSON.parse() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps:

- You need to change `''` inside your `myData` to `""`
- You need to create a `function` which would check if the given value is valid JSON array using `try` and `catch`.
- Then use `reduce()` and check if the current value is valid array so convert it into array using `JSON.parse()` and add it as the `ac`
- If its not valid array so set value as the previous one

```js
let obj = {file: "file.doc", myData: '["dat1","dat2"]'}

function IsJsonString(str) {
  try {
    var json = JSON.parse(str);
    return (Array.isArray(json));
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

let res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((ac,key) => {
  if(IsJsonString(obj[key])){
    ac[key] = JSON.parse(obj[key])
  }
  else ac[key] = obj[key]
  return ac;
  
},{})
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I just need to remove the outside double quotes from: myData: "['dat1','dat2']" ... I don't need to change the single quotes inside.

Comment: @Paul C No thats because for `JSON.parse` string should have `"` not `'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
var obj = {file: "file.doc", myData: "['dat1','dat2']"}
//turn myData into an array.
var arr = obj.myData.split("["); // ["", "'dat1','dat2']"]
//remove the first (empty string) element.
arr.splice(0, 1); // ["'dat1','dat2']"]
//convert the other element (string) into an array of 2 
  elements.
var newArr = arr[0].split(","); //["'dat1'", "'dat2']"]
//declare an empty array
var finalArr = [];
//loop over newArr  array, and push the result of cutting the 
  string from index 1 to 4
for (const element of newArr ) {
finalArr.push(element.substring(1, 4));
}
//reassign the value of myData property of obj object.
obj.myData = finalArr;
console.log(obj.myData); //["dat1", "dat2"]
```